# Programmatically disable apt unattended upgrades

Tags: 16.04, apt

How can I programmatically/script disable apt unattended upgrades? Running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 9):

Several methods exists:

Method One

1. Turn off automatic upgrade by reconfiguring `unattended-upgrades` in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file:

   - Comment out individual lines in the `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` set of rule:-

     ```
     Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
         "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
         //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
         //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
         //      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
     };
     ```
2. Selectively disable auto-update on a package level, by adding package names to "Unattened-Upgrade:Package-Blacklist" set of rules:

   ```
   Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
       //      "vim";
       //      "libc6";
   };
   ```

Method Two

1. Disable auto-update system-wide from the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file:

   - `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`:

     ```
     APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
     APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";
     APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "0";
     APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0"; <--- line of interest, should be "0"
     ```

Method Three:

Go to `Ubuntu Software Center`, `Edit --> Software Sources`, choose `Never` for `Automatically check for update`

[image]

Source (including images):

http://ask.xmodulo.com/disable-automatic-updates-ubuntu.html

Comment: I've updated /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic but I still see activity in /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log -- I'm going to try method #1 now

Comment: You can also "disable" it by uninstalling the unattended-upgrades package.

Comment: @ShaneH that is because there is file /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades (due to unattended-upgrades package) which overrides the settings in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic. So you should change that, too.

Comment: @ShaneH or use kubanczyk's answer to override even  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.

Answer (score 4):

Easier and less fragile method (I think less fragile than `apt remove unattended-upgrades`) is:

```bsh
cp  /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/20auto-upgrades-disabled  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
```

I've verified it by looking at `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`

Answer (score 4):

You can just remove unattended upgrades which takes a dpkg lock:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove unattended-upgrades
```

Or just disable it via configuration:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
```

and make sure to have this line with zero value:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```