# Suppress all unneeded internet traffic when connecting through satellite

Tags: networking, updates, internet, firewall

When using a satellite connection to connect to the internet (I'm on the Thuraya network), traffic is very expensive (around 3,50 USD per MB). Thus, I'd like to suppress all unneeded traffic, i.e. everything except my email client, a browser, and outgoing SSH connections.

Specifically, I want to avoid any updates being fetched in the background. Also, preventing any other programs I haven't thought of from accessing the internet would be great.

How can I do that on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Is it okay for you to block all traffic using firewall and only allow some?

Comment: Well, I thought of that, but when allowing traffic to port 443 (which I need for the web browser), that could still let some update-checking traffic through.

Comment: This might be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/953779/programmatically-disable-apt-unattended-upgrades

Comment: Using a proxy would be a good option I guess, block all traffics and only allow connections to that proxy then setup your browser and email client to use that proxy, if you have an always running server I can write an answer that uses `ssh` + `ufw` to route your traffic.