# Can I keep the annoying dpkg lock error from coming back?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Is there a way one can **permanently** deal with this ever recurring error of:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process
```

And:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

I have tried all the `sudo rm` solutions but it keeps coming back over and over again.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.03.

Comment: The easy was is to stop opening more than one package manager at a time. I almost NEVER get this particular error, and the few times I do are because Unattended Upgrades happens to be running. Just wait a few minutes until it completes. Interrupting dpkg is very unwise - you risk breaking your system quite horribly. Lockfiles are there to protect you from precisely that folly. In over 15 years of using Debian and Ubuntu, I've had to remove a lockfile exactly once...and that was due to a problem I made for myself.

Comment: @user535733 Would you be willing to post that (or something like it) as an answer?

Comment: Updates are important, so don't forget to check manually. Possible duplicate of [Programmatically disable apt unattended upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953779/programmatically-disable-apt-unattended-upgrades)

Comment: And you can look at the output of top to see what all is going on "behind the scenes" to cause "dpkg frontend is locked by another process".

Answer (score 0):

**Package manager lock errors usually occur only under one of the following circumstances:**

- You happen, by chance, to be running two package manager applications (Synaptic, apt, Software Center, etc.) at the same time. This is a reasonably common mistake made once or twice by new users. This one is easy to solve: Use only one at a time. Do NOT abort a running package manager - wait for it to finish.

  Since they all share a common database of packages and a common cache of deb files, only one application may use the database and cache at a time. The lockfiles prevent terrible damage that might result from two simultaneous operations on the same database of filesystem.
- You happen, by chance,  to be using a package manager during the minute-or-two each day that the Unattended Upgrades application is quietly installing security updates. This one is also very easy to solve: Wait a minute or two and try again. Do NOT attempt to abort Unattended Upgrades - let it finish.

  Here's one easy command to tell if Unattended Upgrades is blocking your use of apt: Look for the apt-daily-upgrade.timer. If the timer has very recently passed, then Unattended Upgrades is a likely culprit.

  ```
  $ systemctl list-timers apt-daily-upgrade.timer
  NEXT                         LEFT    LAST                         PASSED  UNIT                    ACTIVATES
  Tue 2019-09-10 06:26:27 CDT  23h left Mon 2019-09-09 06:26:12 CDT  2m ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer apt-daily-upgrade.service
  ```

  In this case, Unattended Upgrades was triggered two minutes ago, and will run again tomorrow. That's why my apt job was blocked by a lockfile. I simply wait for UU to finish, then my apt job will run properly.
- Your system or filesystem was not shutdown cleanly, but instead was powered off or lost read/write access to disk *while in the middle of a package operation*. That has the potential to be REALLY BAD, and might occasionally make your system unbootable, so try not to let that happen. In this case, manually removing a lockfile with `sudo rm` is required since the original application terminated before removing it's lock.

  (In my 15 years using Debian and Ubuntu on many, many systems, I have needed to manually remove a lockfile for this reason only once. And the underlying cause was my fault, not Ubuntu's.)
- Finally and very rarely, frequent recurrence of mysterious lockfiles might be a symptom of damage to your system, or perhaps a bug that you have discovered. Either way, don't assume everybody else is suffering. We're probably not.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens all the time it is likely due to `apt` being locked at boot.

For example:

```
$ systemctl status apt*
● apt-daily.timer - Daily apt download activities
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2019-09-04 04:35:25 MDT; 5 days ago

Sep 04 04:35:25 alien systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.

● apt-daily-upgrade.timer - Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2019-09-04 04:35:25 MDT; 5 days ago

Sep 04 04:35:25 alien systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
```

These services are loaded automatically at startup. If they encounter an error they might never end. You will need to disable them so you can start finding the error and fix it.

```
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
sudo reboot
```

Now they won't be running and locking up your `apt` system. You can run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install -f
```

etc, etc. and see what error messages are present.

After fixing the error condition reenable the services:

```
sudo systemctl enable apt-daily.timer
sudo systemctl enable apt-daily-upgrade.timer
```

Answers on other posts recommending to kill the lock file maybe totally unnecessary and can cause more harm than good. Many of those answers were posted before systemd was invented / published.

We need to establish if the lock is held from boot up until shut down. Additional reading:

- [Debian 9 runs apt update on startup, blocks user apt commands #2621](https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/2621)