# Can I remove the unattended upgrades package from my notebook system?

Tags: apt, package-management, configuration

As far as I can tell, I don't enable/use unattended upgrades on my notebook system (kubuntu 18.04), but it looks like my system is checking it during shutdown.

Is there any reason why I even need this package on my system?

I selected it for removal (without actually removing it) and it didn't pull in any other packages to be autoremoved.

Comment: How do you know that "… my system is checking it during shutdown."? Anyway, since it seems to be a clean removal it may be safe. You could also take a look at the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953779/programmatically-disable-apt-unattended-upgrades).

Comment: Feel free to remove that package, it's the first thing I do on all my fresh installs

Comment: @DKBose I press Esc during shutdown and see console log messages referencing it.